# Aestan tray menu error- no tray icon was specified

Tags: symfony, wampserver

While running Wamp,I got this error :

> Aestan tray menu error- no tray icon was specified

I tried already the solutions posted by other members of this community but in vain.I even tried to install it another time,the same problem is persiting.

- WampServer version : 3.1.0
- Apache Version : 2.4.27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the **wampmanager.ini** file and replace it by a new one.The **httpd.conf** was corrupted I replace it with a new one from the same version installed in an other laptop.

Comment: I am struggling to fix it. Please advise any solution